# How to get the items which are going to expire as per the compliance retention policy

Tags: sharepoint-online, records-management

Is there any way where we can get all the items which are going to expire(due to compliance retention policy) in 7 days from a site collection.

I can see there is value expiration status in the compliance details of an item but I am not sure how can I use this to get the all items in a site collection which are going to expire.

[image]